# Shortcutting classes affect performance?

Tags: php

Two pieces of code that do the same thing:

```
class Dog
{
   public $name;
   public $breed;
}
$hachi = new Dog;
$hachi->name = "Hachi";
$hachi->breed = "Shiba";
```

vs

```
$hachi->name = "Hachi";
$hachi->breed = "Shiba";
```

In this context (using the class as a struct), both code will achieve the same thing. Is there any benefit for using the long-winded version besides readability/style? Are there performance issues or anything else that should prevent me from short-cutting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually yes, even aside from the obvious maintainability issue there is another benefit. With pre-declared properties PHP only needs a single hashtable per class that maps the property names to offsets in memory-efficient C arrays used for each object. Using dynamic properties PHP needs a hashtable per object.

So as soon as you've got more than one object of that type, you're saving memory.

---

How much? Let's pretend you've got a *lot* of dogs.

"long-winded" version:

```
class Dog
{
    public $name;
    public $breed;
}

while (@$i++ < 1000000) {
    $hachi = new Dog();
    $hachi->name = "Hachi";
    $hachi->breed = "Shiba";
    $dogs[] = $hachi;
}

echo memory_get_usage(true); //188747776
```

"short-cut" version:

```
while (@$i++ < 1000000) {
    $hachi = new stdClass();
    $hachi->name = "Hachi";
    $hachi->breed = "Shiba";
    $dogs[] = $hachi;
}

echo memory_get_usage(true); //524292096
```

For a difference of 524292096 - 188747776 = 335,544,320 bytes.

---

For a lengthier explanation see: [*Why objects (usually) use less memory than arrays in PHP*](https://gist.github.com/nikic/5015323)

Comment: Very fascinating, and just what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: To extend this answer, in addition to using less memory, the 'long version' executes about twice as fast as the 'short version'

Answer (score 1):

Classes are intended to help organize data, and that definitely adds overhead.

If you are trying to write code that does a good job representing the data you will be working with, you will have to accept some performance penalties.

The second approach will create code that is virtually impossible to maintain.

> PHP gives us a very simple way to define an object programmatically,
>   and this is called a class. A class is a wrapper that defines and
>   encapsulates the object along with all of its methods and properties.
>   You can think of a class as a programmatic representation of an
>   object, and it is the interface that PHP has given you, the developer,
>   to interact with and modify the object. Moreover, a class may be
>   re-used infinitely if need be, making it very powerful and codebase
>   friendly. You do not have to redefine things every time you want to
>   use an object - a properly coded class is setup to do all of the work
>   for you.

From: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/object-orientated-programming-in-php-class-1-principles.html

Comment: 2nd approach will be harder to maintain but without the penalty? Or is it the same either way?

Comment: The second approach does not define the properties of the class - so people could code the class differently, which defeats it.

Comment: Assuming I'm the only maintainer. Plus even with the first approach, you could still define new properties in the same way

Comment: .. I know what a class is. Just wanted to know the short-cut approach differences.

Answer (score -1):

if both codes work then go for the short one, adding it into a class will not make it any faster or efficient, its good practice and can help if you are adding allot of code to generate it. But performance wise the second one will work better